# Remove one element at a time from a vector: Leave one out

Tags: r, rows

I have a vector x
x = c(1:10)

i want to iteratively remove one element from the vector. For example in the first iteration i want to remove the first element while retaining the other elements. In the second iteration i want to remove only the second element while retaining the other elements,so on and forth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of your another question

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760487/how-to-delete-an-element-at-a-time-from-a-vector-while-retaining-the-others

Comment: @akrun My bad. I felt that i was not clear here about my query. Is there a way i can remove this, if i must?

Comment: I think it is okay to keep it as one person has already replied on your post.  It is better in the future to edit the original post.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it enough ? :

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  a = x[-i]
  print(a)
}
```

Here you've got every iteration without the element corresponding