# How to delete an element at a time from a vector while retaining the others?

Tags: r, vector, row

I have a vector `x` containing 5 elements.

```
x <- (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I would want to delete one element at each iteration and retain other elements in the vector.(as shown below)

```
x <- (2,3,4,5)     #vector after first iteration 

x <- (1,3,4,5)     #vector after second iteration 

x <- (1,2,4,5)     #vector after third iteration 

x <- (1,2,3,5)     #vector after fourth iteration
```

and also, is it possible to store these new vectors in a list?
is there a way to extend this to multiple vectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `combn`:

```
combn(5,4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    2    3    3
[3,]    3    3    4    4    4
[4,]    4    5    5    5    5
```

To get the data as a `list`:

```
as.list(data.frame(combn(5,4)))
```

To use this on multiple vectors or a matrix, first transform it into a `data.frame`, to make it easier for `lapply` to go over the length (columns) of the `data.frame`. Then you can use `lapply` with `combn` like so:

```
mat <- data.frame(matrix(1:10,5))
lapply(mat, function(x) combn(x,length(x)-1))

$X1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    2    3    3
[3,]    3    3    4    4    4
[4,]    4    5    5    5    5

$X2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6    6    6    6    7
[2,]    7    7    7    8    8
[3,]    8    8    9    9    9
[4,]    9   10   10   10   10
```

Comment: How can i extend this to multiple vectors or a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[-i])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
drop_n <- function(n, x) x[-n]
lapply(1:5, drop_n, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a way to get what you want. You only need to change the parameter `n` to make it more general

```
    # Generate a list
      L <- list()
    # Define the number of elements
      n <- 5
    # Define the values
      values <- 1:n

    # Complete the list
      for (i in 1:n){
        L[[i]] <- values[-i]
      }
```

Comment: How can i extend this to a matrix?. Say if want to delete a row after each iteration.

Comment: If you have a matrix `M`, to omit the i-th row, just use `M[-i,]`